# Firebase RecyclerView databaseexception: use generic type indicator error

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

We are so close to make our prototype app in Android Studio but we keep getting a persistent error when we switch to one of our activities. The activity with the problem basically shows a list of users in CardViews. The error we get is `com.firebase.database.databaseexception class java.util.HashMap, has generic type parameters, please use Generic type indicator instead`. The object that the Firebase RecyclerView is capturing does store a hashmap but I don't know if that's the problem. The RecyclerView isn't printing anything related to the hashmap, it's just a stored item in the object. If someone could help that would be great. The bug starts when you hit the initialization of the Firebase RecyclerView options. If anyone could help, I need this fixed quickly, thanks\

```
public class TutorDisplay extends BaseNavigationActivity {

    private RecyclerView tutorList;

    private DatabaseReference dataRef;

    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Tutor, TutorDisplay.TutorViewHolder> TutorAdapator;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_tutor_display, frameLayout);
        setTitle("Tutors");

        //Establish Firebase connection
        //FirebaseDatabase myData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        dataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        dataRef.keepSynced(true);

        tutorList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.tutorList);
        tutorList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        tutorList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        DatabaseReference personsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        Query personsQuery = personsRef.orderByChild("type").startAt("Tutor").endAt("Tutor");
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions Options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Tutor>().setQuery(personsQuery, Tutor.class).build();


        TutorAdapator = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Tutor, TutorViewHolder>(Options) {
            @Override
            //sets the inputs in specified spots or AKA binds them to the card
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TutorDisplay.TutorViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final Tutor model) {
                holder.setTutor(model.getName());
                holder.setRating(model.getRating());

                holder.btProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // Convert the tutor into a parcel to send to the profile activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(TutorDisplay.this, ProfileCard.class);

                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                holder.btMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(TutorDisplay.this, ChatActivity.class));
                    }
                });
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            //creates a new view or Card holder
            public TutorDisplay.TutorViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                //creates a new view which is inherited from the parent view
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tutor_card, parent, false);

                return new TutorDisplay.TutorViewHolder(view);
            }
        };

        //Start the Database and view
        //firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
        //create the Recycler view
        tutorList.setAdapter(TutorAdapator);
    }

public static class TutorViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //create new view
        View mView;

        //UI elements
        Button btProfile;
        Button btMessage;
        Button btRate;

        //constructor
        public TutorViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;

            //initialize UI
            btProfile = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.profileButton);
            btMessage = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.messageButton);
            btRate = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.rateButton);
        }

        //sets the name of the Tutor
        public void setTutor(String name) {
            TextView tutorName = (TextView) 
mView.findViewById(R.id.tutorName);
            tutorName.setText(name);
        }

        //sets the rating of the Tutor
        public void setRating(float rating) {
            RatingBar starRating = (RatingBar) `enter code 
here`mView.findViewById(R.id.tutorRatingBar);
            starRating.setRating(rating);
        }
    }

@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
          TutorAdapator.startListening();
        //Starts to get info from firebase


    }
}
```

Comment: Please post some of your related code so that we can help.

Comment: Please add the code that you are using to display the data.

Comment: I edited the first question with code

Comment: Can you format the code please? Please you also responde with @AlexMamo ?

Comment: Sorry I'm doing this off my phone, bare with me

Comment: ok thank you guys for your patience i added the code

Comment: @ReazMurshed I added my code

Comment: @AlexMamo I added my code now, please have a look

Comment: Please add also your database structure.

Comment: Thanks for all the help I solved it, there was something wrong with my tutor class.